# Django Template Error :TemplateDoesNotExist at / homepage/index.html

Tags: django

I'm attempting to get the Django development server to load a template with the following settings but it's throwing the error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

homepage/index.html
```

Below are the files that I've edited to try to get this to work

blog/blog/settings.py - (Cut the portion pertaining to this question)

```
import os

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates' ),
)
```

blog/apps/homepage/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('homepage/index.html')
```

Any thoughts about how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Django uses two template loaders to locate templates:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

First the filesystem loader checks all dirs in TEMPLATE_DIRS to see if it can find the named template. If that fails the app_directories loader will look in the /templates/ dir in the current app for the named template. This way you can ship default templates with reusable apps that can easily be overridden.

In your case Django will look for the template here:

```
blog/blog/templates/homepage/index.html
blog/apps/homepage/templates/homepage/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You give a wrong direction to your `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. The `settings.py` file is in package `blog` in project `blog`, but your `templates` folder is in `blog` project, not in `blog` package. You must give the absolute directory of your project and join `templates` with it.

Answer (score 0):

in django 1.10, navigate to path/to/settings.py in your parent project directory, look for:

`TEMPLATES = [.....]` and specify the path/to/project_directory in the `DIR:` option

for example (in my own case):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        '/xampp/htdocs/advisory_portal'
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```